# Have one way to toggle a site-wide message

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to have a site-wide message that can be toggled in a single place. On the `<front>` page, this site will appear in one location in the UI. On every other page, it will appear in a different location.

Here's the approach I've come up with:

1. In "Custon Block Library" (`/admin/structure/block/block-content`), create a custom block with the right content
2. In "Block Layout" (`/admin/structure/block`), add the block to both places I want it to appear.

To show the alert message:

1. Set the front page block to show on `<front>`
2. Set the other page block to hide on `<front>`

To hide the alert message:

1. Set both blocks to hide on `*`

This seems like it will work, but I'd rather have a single place to toggle the message. Is it possible to say "site-wide, I want to hide / show this block"? Or are blocks the wrong solution for this?

Comment: Looks like the Rules plugin may be what I want. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18965/is-there-a-way-to-set-block-visibility-programmatically-without-using-the-php-fi/204555#204555